# Regex key to match only a line(s)?

Tags: python, regex

My issue is that I am trying to write a regex key to find certain line(s). Here is the data

```
| |-UsingDirectiveDecl 0x16de688 <line:58:3, col:24> col:24 Namespace 0x16de588 '__debug'
|-UsingDirectiveDecl 0x1e840b8 <simple.cpp:2:1, col:17> col:17 Namespace 0x1378e98 'std'
```

and here is the regex code

```
import subprocess as subs
import os
import re


file = "simple.cpp"

full_ast = subs.run(["clang -Xclang -ast-dump %s" % file], shell=True, stdout=subs.PIPE) # , (" > %s.xml" % title)


namespace_s = re.search("UsingDirectiveDecl\s0x([+-]?(?=\.\d|\d)(?:\d+)?(?:\.?\d*))(?:[eE]([+-]?\d+))?\s<simple\.cpp:[0-9]+:[0-9]+,\s[a-zA-Z]+][0-9]+>\s[a-zA-Z]+:[0-9]+\sNamespace\s0x([+-]?(?=\.\d|\d)(?:\d+)?(?:\.?\d*))(?:[eE]([+-]?\d+))?\s'[^']*'", str(full_ast.stdout))

# not sure if re.search is the right module.

print(namespace_s)
```

I'm tring to match the bottom line, only I have had any success. Two thing I would like to happen, 1: where there is a  offset like 0x1e840b8  I need it to match as 0x7hexcharacters - originally I tried 0x[a-z0-9]{7} but that didn't work. 2: How can I put the file name in, would it work with %s then joining the key with % file

Any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the regex, you are trying to match `(?:\d+)?(?:\.?\d*))(?:[eE]([+-]?\d+))?` on the places with the hex part, but you can use `0x[a-f0-9]{7}` instead.

If you are matching, you don't need the lookahead `(?=\.\d|\d)`

There is also an extra closing bracket `]` that is not in the example data, that should be a `:`

```
<simple\.cpp:[0-9]+:[0-9]+,\s[a-zA-Z]+]
                                      ^
```

See for example this pattern:

```
UsingDirectiveDecl\s0x[a-f0-9]{7}\s+<simple\.cpp:[0-9]+:[0-9]+,\s[a-zA-Z]+:[0-9]+>\s[a-zA-Z]+:[0-9]+\sNamespace\s0x[a-f0-9]{7}\s'[^']*'
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/7W0VU9/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/KVnBRq)

Example

```
import re

pattern = r"UsingDirectiveDecl\s0x[a-f0-9]{7}\s+<simple\.cpp:[0-9]+:[0-9]+,\s[a-zA-Z]+:[0-9]+>\s[a-zA-Z]+:[0-9]+\sNamespace\s0x[a-f0-9]{7}\s'[^']*'"

s = ("test | |-UsingDirectiveDecl 0x16de688 <line:58:3, col:24> col:24 Namespace 0x16de588 '__debug' test\n"
            "test |-UsingDirectiveDecl 0x1e840b8 <simple.cpp:2:1, col:17> col:17 Namespace 0x1378e98 'std' test")

print(re.findall(pattern, s))
```

Output

```
["UsingDirectiveDecl 0x1e840b8 <simple.cpp:2:1, col:17> col:17 Namespace 0x1378e98 'std'"]
```

Comment: Thank you so much for that. My next problem is adapting it to the code as I'm not getting the full line. re.search, fullmatch and match return None, findall produces an empty array, but finditer returns <callable_iterator object at 0x7f89fc18e610>. Do you know how I can fix this? Thank you

Comment: @BillaBongJr. Try prepending and appending `.*` to the pattern

Comment: No it's still not working. Does it run properly for you? When you mean prepend and append do you mean -  ".*UsingDirectiveDecl    ...    [^']'.*"   . If so that doesn't seem to work.   The other thing I think it could mean is where there is |- at the beginning of the line could be playing up.

Comment: @BillaBongJr. I have added a Python demo and some demo code.

Comment: Yes it does work, however I have finally pin pointed the other problem. That is where I use str(full_ast.stdout) in the namespace_s, it still shows None, this I think is a problem with the conversion. Do you need the full output of full_ast? Or is this a problem for another question?